# Pycharm menu bar disappearing

Tags: xubuntu, python, java, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm Community Edition 2020.1 version. Operation system is Xubuntu 20, Java version is openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14

I faced a strange problem today. I lost menu bar in pycharm. I searched this problem in google but all answers are not working. Please look to my problem:

[image]
Menu bar appearing when loading the project.

.....

[image]
Menu bar is gone away after the project loaded.

.....

[image]
I changed shortcut for menu visibility but not worked.

I removed and reinstalled pycharm but not working. Please help me before I eat my head :( Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I'M using xfce4-panel and I was added Indicator Plugin. Indicator Plugin is capturing menu of current program. It is capturing but not showing. I removed the Indicator Plugin from xfce4-panel and problem is gone.